# What is transaction-managed data blocks?

Tags: oracle, oracle-12c

While reading the [Database Concepts (Oracle 12c)](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e40540/logical.htm#CNCPT1046) I found the following:

> Block header: This part contains general information about the block,
>   including disk address and segment type. For blocks that are
>   transaction-managed, the block header contains active and historical
>   transaction information.

I want to know what's is a transaction-managed block?

Comment: Oracle site that might be useful: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28318/logical.htm#CNCPT004

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a block that can be modified transactionally.

The best explanation is probably from page 106 in [Tom Kyte's Expert Oracle Database Architecture](https://books.google.com/books?id=3_RUBQAAQBAJ&pg=PA106&lpg=PA106&dq=transaction-managed%20block%20header&source=bl&ots=OEfws6germ&sig=1bY-xcFDnuejl0U4MiqNkCqcfcs&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjOl5Wri6nQAhXn1IMKHZ11DmcQ6AEIQjAG#v=onepage&q=transaction-managed%20block%20header&f=false)

> ... transaction information when relevant (only blocks that are
>   transaction-managed have this information-- a temporary sort block
>   would not, for example) regarding active and past transactions on
>   the block ...

Most blocks, of course, are subject to transactional modification so they would have transaction information.

Comment: Thanks Justin for your time. As I could not imagine any blocks which are not subject transactional modification I was a little confused why it warranted an explicit mention. I think every database block will have sooner or latter transaction information.